# Is it possible to add custom options to VS2010's ctrl-. refactorings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I am wondering if it is possible to add to the built in "refactorings" that VS2010 provides.

For example - when cursor is on an interface, CTRL-. offers to "implement interface members".

1. Do i have access to the actual macro/code that runs this ?
2. Do i have access to actually add my own custom things to be offered in CTRL-. ?